# My latex document can't seem to decode properly accentuated and other special french characters

Tags: texmaker, input-encodings, font-encodings, miktex2.9

My editor (TexMaker) is using utf-8 by default and when i try to use it in my preamble instead of latin it gives me errors! and right now i'm using latin and it dosen't decode properly my document! Any help is much appreciated...

This is the preamble for my document :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\include{Couverture}
\include{Corps}
\include{Bibliographie}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output] And for reference here is the output it gives me to give you an idea of the issue.

Comment: What error do you get with utf8?

Comment: you are turning off utf-8 support with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` just delete that line (or for older latex change it to `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: When i use  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and delete `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` It gives me `Undefined control sequence.<argument>` and `package inputenc error Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`

Comment: then presumably one of your input files is not UTF-8, the error message does show where exactly tex had reached but if you do not show any code or the full error it is hard to say. The undefined command error message also says which command is undefined. You need to look in the log not your editors "summary" of the errors.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing the input encoding of some of my documents because Some used latin while others unicoding which completely slipped out of my mind lol